# Job / Work Queue for URL access queue

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, queue, message-queue

Is there any Job or Work queue server that can be used to handle these parameters:

1. Queue a HTTP call to external URL with Form parameters (HTTP Post to URL)
2. The external URL will respond HTTP response, 200, 404, 400 etc, if response is in form of error non-200-ish response it will retry for a certain number of retry and will *retire* as needed
3. Something that can be used in a Java application through REST API call to Job / Work server or through SDK (Library) if available

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be something for this, but click here and read about [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/intro), I think this can solve your problem. Still I am not sure if you should use it for this requirement.

Comment: I think this is more like a low-level implementation, what I need is quite high-level

Comment: camel/kafka with retries would be a good choice. Producer will produce a message with url/data. consumer will consume and makes a http call and then retries based on configuration. If you don't want to use messaging queues you can always use http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry but it will come at cost of starvation.